# Perc per football cluf of the total points

Tags: mysql, sql, rstudio

I want to calculate the percentage of points of the total per club. below is my code that doesn't work yet. Because I don't get a result back yet. In the picture you can see the data structure as stated. Also looked at other solutions on stackoverflow but didn't find the desired result.

```
select f.ClubName, count(u.p) * 100.0 / sum(count(u.p)) over()
From fact f
join uitslag u
on u.StandID = f.StandID
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to `group by clubname` and `sum()` instead of `count()`:

```
select f.ClubName, 
  sum(u.p) * 100.0 / sum(sum(u.p)) over()
From fact f
join uitslag u
on u.StandID = f.StandID
group by f.clubname
```

See a [simplified](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kPYSNdDbLNNSbdaDxoYH6r/0) demo.